# How do I align PanedWindows in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm new to Tkinter, and finding it a bit rough to get the hang of it. The point of this piece of code is to calculate time using the equation (Time = (Velocity - Initial Velocity) / Acceleration) But I need to take user input for the variables.

Here's what I have so far. It would be great, except for the fact that the labels don't line up with the text widgets. Is there any easy way to do what I need?

```
    def timF():
        timPanel = Toplevel()
        timPanel.wm_title("Time")

        timCont = PanedWindow(timPanel, orient=VERTICAL)
        timCont.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # Top Paned Window and contents #
        timTopCont = PanedWindow(timCont, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        timCont.add(timTopCont)

        # Velocity label
        timFVelL = Label(timTopCont, text="Velocity")
        timTopCont.add(timFVelL)

        # Initial Velocity label
        timFiveL = Label(timTopCont, text="Initial Velocity")
        timTopCont.add(timFiveL)

        # Acceleration label
        timFaccL = Label(timTopCont, text="Acceleration")
        timTopCont.add(timFaccL)


        # Bottom Paned Window and contents #
        timBotCont = PanedWindow(timCont, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        timCont.add(timBotCont)

        # Velocity entry
        timFVelE = Entry(timBotCont)

        timBotCont.add(timFVelE)
        # Initial Velocity entry
        timFiveE = Entry(timBotCont)

        timBotCont.add(timFiveE)
        # Acceleration entry
        timFAccE = Entry(timBotCont)

        timBotCont.add(timFAccE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`grid()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) to place the widgets, instead of `pack()`. It is the easiest way to do so if you know the concrete row and column of the layout you want to place each widget:

```
timFVelL.grid(row=0, column=0)
timFVelE.grid(row=0, column=1)
timFiveL.grid(row=1, column=0)
timFiveE.grid(row=1, column=1)
# ...
```

Comment: I have this a try, but I didn't notice any change. The text and boxes stayed in the same location.

Comment: First you have to remove your `PanedWindow` object, and set the toplevel as the parent of the widgets.